# shell scrript - how to get key name of nested json

Tags: json, bash, sh, jq

I have a json in the format like below. I just want to get key name of those fields which are nested arrays. for below json, I want to get in output key-name equals to "cd"  because that is the only one which is nested.
Is there any command which can be used to get this value.

```
{
  "ab": null,
  "cd": [
    "ST",
    "CO:,
  ],
  "EF": 0,
  "GH": 0,
  "IJ": null,
  "IK": true,
},
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a way of getting the desired output using jq.

```
jq 'to_entries[]|select(.value|type == "array")|.key' <<< '
{
  "ab": null,
  "cd": [ "ST","CO" ],
  "EF": 0,
  "GH": 0,
  "IJ": null,
  "IK": true
}'
```

Note that I modified the input to make it valid json.

To see how it works, start with looking at what the command jq 'to_entries' returns. Once you see that, the rest should be pretty clear.